# Access to a member data via a class template specialisation

Tags: c++, template-specialization, template-classes

I can not access the member data "value" defined in the template class from the specialized one. Why?
Some one can help me?
Thanks

```
template <class T>
class A {

public:

  int value;

  A() {
    value = 0;
  }

};


template <> class A<int> {

public:

  A() {
    value = 3;  // Use of undeclared identifier 'value'
    A::value = 3; // No member named 'value' in 'A<int>'
    this->value = 3; // No member named 'value' in 'A<int>'
  }

};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An explicit specialization is like a whole new thing. You can't access anything from  the explicit specialization of `A<int>` in the primary template, because it's just like a totally different class.

But, it seems like you want to only specialize the constructor. In that case, you can do that:

```
template <> 
A<int>::A() {
    value = 3;  // ok
}
```

This works because you are only specializing the constructor, and the rest of the class is taken from the primary template.

Comment: Thank you very much! all is now clear to me. But what is the point of do a explicit specialization if you can not access to the member of the primary template?

Comment: @thewoz Well, explicit specialization is used when you need to do something different for a specific type. In general, you don't need anything from the primary template. If you do however need the same things in both, the normal technique is create a non-template base class that you then inherit from both the primary and the explicit specialization.

Comment: ok understood. The example is a simplification on what in reality I need. int value; should be T value; and beyond that to have a specialization of the constructor I will need a specialization of some function.

Comment: @thewoz If they are doing something else, then yes.